# How to center text content in tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a very basic game where you can move around on a 2D plane made out of normal characters. However I can't seem to get the "world"-text to be centralized in the main label.

I'm thinking there might be some hidden empty spaces but I've not managed to find anymore at this point. Especially on the right side there seems to be an empty column or something?

Any help will be very appreciated and please bear with my code. Cheers!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

coordinates = {
    "x1y1": "#", "x1y2": "#", "x1y3": "#", "x1y4": "#", "x1y5": "#", "x1y6": "#", "x1y7": "#", "x1y8": "#", "x1y9": "#", "x1y10": "#",
    "x2y1": "#", "x2y2": "#", "x2y3": "#", "x2y4": "#", "x2y5": "#", "x2y6": "#", "x2y7": "#", "x2y8": "#", "x2y9": "#", "x2y10": "#",
    "x3y1": "#", "x3y2": "#", "x3y3": "#", "x3y4": "#", "x3y5": "#", "x3y6": "#", "x3y7": "#", "x3y8": "#", "x3y9": "#", "x3y10": "#",
    "x4y1": "#", "x4y2": "#", "x4y3": "#", "x4y4": "#", "x4y5": "#", "x4y6": "#", "x4y7": "#", "x4y8": "#", "x4y9": "#", "x4y10": "#",
    "x5y1": "#", "x5y2": "#", "x5y3": "#", "x5y4": "#", "x5y5": "#", "x5y6": "#", "x5y7": "#", "x5y8": "#", "x5y9": "#", "x5y10": "#",
    "x6y1": "#", "x6y2": "#", "x6y3": "#", "x6y4": "#", "x6y5": "#", "x6y6": "#", "x6y7": "#", "x6y8": "#", "x6y9": "#", "x6y10": "#",
    "x7y1": "#", "x7y2": "#", "x7y3": "#", "x7y4": "#", "x7y5": "#", "x7y6": "#", "x7y7": "#", "x7y8": "#", "x7y9": "#", "x7y10": "#",
    "x8y1": "#", "x8y2": "#", "x8y3": "#", "x8y4": "#", "x8y5": "#", "x8y6": "#", "x8y7": "#", "x8y8": "#", "x8y9": "#", "x8y10": "#",
    "x9y1": "#", "x9y2": "#", "x9y3": "#", "x9y4": "#", "x9y5": "#", "x9y6": "#", "x9y7": "#", "x9y8": "#", "x9y9": "#", "x9y10": "#",
    "x10y1":"#","x10y2": "#", "x10y3":"#", "x10y4":"#", "x10y5":"#", "x10y6":"#", "x10y7":"#", "x10y8":"#", "x10y9":"#", "x10y10":"#",
}

#Player starting position
player_x = 5
player_y = 5


def update_world():

    #Create string with player coordinates and input into dictionary
    player_xy = "x", player_x, "y", player_y
    player_coord = ''.join(map(str, player_xy))
    coordinates[player_coord] = '€'

    #Update previous player tile to map tile
    coord_keys = coordinates.keys()
    for coords in coord_keys:
        if coords != player_coord:
            coordinates[coords] = ' '

    #Print map
    width = 10
    coord_values = coordinates.values()
    i=0
    world=""

    for item in coord_values:
        world = world + item + " "
        i += 1
        if i % width == 0:
            world = world + '\n'
        if i == 100:
            world = world[:-1]

    #refresh the label that displays the world
    world_label.place(y=90, x=1)
    world_label.configure(font=("Courier", 24), text=world, bg="AliceBlue", anchor="center", width=20, height=10)


root = Tk() #Create window
root.configure(background="white")


world_label = Label() #Create World Label widget
world_label.pack()

update_world() #Function update_world


root.geometry("1200x800") #Size of window 
root.title('Game 0.1') #Title of window 
root.mainloop() #
```

Comment: If the question is about centering the text, the example doesn't need to include the function used to move the character. See [mcve] for how to create a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I have removed as much as possible to make it quicker to read through!

Comment: You have 10x10 *2D world* , putting `'€'` at (5, 5) will never be at center of the *world*.  Make the world 9x9.

Comment: @acw1668 I think I might've been unclear. It's not about where '€' is placed but the whole text inside the 'world'-variable. The variable is offcenter in label 'world_label' for some reason.

Comment: It is because extra space is added at the end of each line by this code `world = world + item + " "`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you so I was on the right track.. however I can't find a proper way of removing the " " after each 10th iteration, is that possible?

I tried messing around with this below but it doesn't seem to  work the way I want it to:

`if i == 10:
            world = world[:-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is extra space at the end of each line added by the following code:

```py
for item in coord_values:
    world = world + item + " "
    ...
```

To remove the extra space, modify the for loop as below:

```py
for item in coord_values:
    world = world + item + " "
    i += 1
    if i % width == 0:
        world = world[:-1] + '\n'   # use world[:-1] instead of world
world = world[:-1]
```

However I would suggest to modify the for loop as below:

```py
world = []
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    world.append(' '.join(coord_values[i:i+10]))
world = '\n'.join(world)
# one-liner for the above:
# world = '\n'.join(' '.join(coord_values[i:i+10]) for i in range(0, 100, 10))
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple fix! 

Also the loop looks much better that way, I haven't used range yet but I'll take a look at it asap.